# Using as3xls how to make only first row values bold?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, flex4, flex3

I am using as3xls.swc for my datagrid to export as excel. everything went well but according to my requirement, the exported excel sheet should have the first Row values to be bolded because they are column headers. So, I tried in many ways but it did not work, can anyone just help me please.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

AS3XLS does not support this. You would need to use Excel2007 xml. See here for an example with our Flexicious component http://blog.flexicious.com/post/Flexicious-30-Release-Grid-Edition.aspx